# Is there way to display an image hiding/cutting its unneeded margine?

Tags: css, image, margin

I've an [image with blue frame/margine](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0219/0154/products/1203ab_N1_1024x1024.jpg).
How to display it hiding or cutting that margine, with eg. CSS, to be like this:
[image]

Comment: clip-path: inset(50px) ?

Comment: What margin? I don't see any margin. I don't see any markup of any kind!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Temani Afiff said, just use the *clip-path*.
In your case:

```
<img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0219/0154/products/1203ab_N1_1024x1024.jpg" style="clip-path: inset(56px);">
```

Comment: Note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification

Comment: Rob is right: self-closing tags (<tag />) do not exist in HTML. I edited and corrected the example code.